# Gradle project sync failed error after invalidating caches/restart?

Tags: android, gradle

I am running android 3.4.1 and all I did was invalidate caches and restart now I get the error gradle sync issues and this

**ERROR: Failed to parse XML in C:\Users\J.Robinson\AndroidStudioProjects\App\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
ParseError at [row,col]:[17,64]
Message: expected start or end tag**

I've google stack for an hour and a half now and nothing seems to work. How do I solve this?

[Image of error in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzpeU.png)

**Manifest.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jstudios.curbyourmeme">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="App"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="app"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please add your manifest code

Comment: The error probably appears now only because the cache deletion/restart triggered a reparsing of the XML.

Comment: That's probably what happened Peter. Ismail I'm going to add the manifest code to the post

Comment: probably at the 17th row and 64th character of your manifest file there is something wrong.

Comment: so look in the manifest xml at this location for an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the > symbol in the line

> android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

It was causing the error

Comment: Wow one mistype was all it took. Thanks a ton, It works now